# Didn't log out of YouTube - Is this a problem?

Tags: google, smart-tv

Recently, when staying in a rented apartment, I signed in to the YouTube app on the smart TV by entering a code using chrome on my tablet to pair them.  I was planning to log out before I vacated the apartment but forgot to do so.

What are the security implementations of this?  I am not bothered by people seeing my viewing history on YouTube etc., but obviously wouldn't like anyone to access any other google services via my account.

Comment: Does [this](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/3893071?hl=en) help?

Comment: Pretty sure Google considered this attack vector and would require the folks in that apartment to sign in again to view or modify anything sensitive. But if you're worried, you can [sign out of all devices at once](https://www.wikihow.com/Sign-Out-of-Your-Google-Account-on-All-Devices-at-Once#:~:text=Go%20to%20your%20Google%20Account,device%20you%20are%20currently%20using.) then change your password.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that the SmartTV cannot share your account session with other devices, but in any case you can remotely close the session by following the guide here: https://appuals.com/sign-google-account-remote-devices/

Comment: Thank you, but the TV is not listed amongst the devices, maybe because I didn't sign in with username and password, but rather I authorised the app via an already signed in device?

Comment: Just a guess, but if you sign out on the Chrome device perhaps that will invalidate the pairing?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I've since now reset my google password, which has logged me out of all my devices, so I'm safe now.